# Html Encode Ionic 2 + API PHP quotes errors

Tags: javascript, php, regex, angular, ionic2

My api returns a string of html in which I convert to html with php with the function:
[API ENCODE HTML, IF NOT IS RENDERIZE AS STRING ]

```
$description = html_entity_decode($description)
```

After this Json_encode
And return this value to the Ionic 2 app.
In which I take this *item* and show with:
[APP HTML RECEIVE WITH NO TRAITAMENT IN INNERHTML TO SHOW DESCRIPTION]

```
<div class="item item-text-wrap" [innerHTML]="item.description"></div>
```

But some items use as a tooltip in the tag:

```
<span title="Auxiliary content open per click">click</span>
```

However, some content breaks due to double quotation marks.

```
title=" table rowspan="2"></table "
```

How could I add slashs or a rendition of that html inside the title without breaking it by the quotation marks.
I've already tried modifying your content in the API, but I have not yet been able to render this html.
Is there a way to do this by ionic 2? as ?
Is there a way to do it with regex in php to modify the title only?
Thanks for the help, and sorry for my bad english.

Not result any erros;
[image: problems when is compiled]

Test for the response 1:

let description = this.item.descricao;
this.descricao = description.replace(/'/g, '"');

Comment: Why decode the entities, I think `&quot;` would render as a quote when selected

Comment: ckeditor generate a string with html and to render as html, i use html_entity_decode to render as html, but if i use html_entities not work as well or override entity_decode.

Comment: I think my problems is with two quotes, broken my HTML.

Comment: Yea, your double quotes close the attribute encapsulation. Not really sure what you have and/or what it should be.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your `""` with `'` as shown below using Javascript/TS.

```
var result = yourString.replace(/'/g, '"');
```

Comment: I am using typescript. Angular with Ionic

Comment: It's not a problem.Typescript is a superset of Javascript.This should work with TS too.

Comment: I write a similar code, but not work for me. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Can you show the code you wrote? Any errors? Please put that on your question above.

Comment: I  explained how receive that data in post and the result of that.
I added a image of the result expected and my result in some cases.
The Code used is based on my code. Can you help me ? thanks

Comment: Where's the code for this `yourString.replace(/'/g, '"');` on your app?

Answer (score 0):

I changed my API PHP to create a json file, every time updated content with CKeditor, I override file make.json.
When app request my API, he read this file like this:

```
  public function make(){
        if(file_exists("web/uploads/make/make.json")){
            $make = file_get_contents('web/uploads/make/make.json');
            echo ($make);
        }else{
            return false;
        }
        die;
    }
```

So, Thank for help me.